# Looping through a nested list and summing all elements of each internal list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration, nested-lists

My problem is as follows: I have a list of lists named 'All_slips.' I would like to loop through each of the lists within the list and sum all of its elements, and then append these sums to a new list called 'Summed_list.' As such my desired output/solution would be a 'Summed_list' = [10,16,19]. A minimum reproducible program is provided below:

```
All_slips = [[1,2,3,4],[1,3,5,7],[1,2,7,9]]
Summed_list = []

for j in All_slips[j][] :
    counter = 0
    for i in All_slips[j][i] :
        counter += i
    Summed_list.insert(len(Summed_list),counter)
    
print (Summed_list)
```

I am new to python and i obtain a syntax error on line 4: 'for j in All_slips[j][]:'. What is the proper syntax to achieve what I stated above - I could not find another post that described this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
summed_list = []
for sublist in All_slips:
    summed_list.append(sum(sublist))
```

That's all. You can also employ a list comprehension.

```
summed_list = [sum(sublist) for sublist in All_slips]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go with functional programming way, here is one solution

```
>>> All_slips = [[1,2,3,4],[1,3,5,7],[1,2,7,9]]
>>> summed_list= list(map(sum , All_slips))
>>> summed_list
[10, 16, 19]
```

otherwise, below would be easy list compreghension one solution

```
summed_list = [sum(sub_list) for sub_list in All_slips]
```

if you want to go with for loop, then store sum of a sublist in a varibale for a single iteration and then save this in `summed_list`

```
suumed_list = []
for sub_list in All_slips:
    sublist_sum = 0
    for val in sub_list:
        sublist_sum+= val
    summed_list.append(sublist_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) for an introduction to `for` loops.

A typical `for` loop in python has a `for item in iterable` type of syntax and you can access the members of the `iterable` using the variable `item` within the loop.

In your case, if you want to maintain the two loops-

```
for inner_list in All_slips:
    inner_sum = 0
    for element in inner_list:
        inner_sum = inner_sum + element
    summmed_list.append(inner_sum)
```

Of course, you don't really have to maintain the two loops as `sum` is a built in function in python -

```
for inner_list in All_slips:
    inner_sum = sum(inner_list)
    summed_list.append(inner_sum)
```

You can take it a step further by using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) -

```
summed_list = [sum(inner_list) for inner_list in All_slips]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in map function. It maps a function to a list of  iterables.

```
map(function, list-of-iterables)
```

Since Python 3 this will get you a map-generator, therefore you might want to make it a list, set or whatever iterable you prefer.

```
list(map(sum, list-of-iterables))
```

So in your case:

```
>>> All_slips = [[1,2,3,4],[1,3,5,7],[1,2,7,9]]
>>> summed_list = list(map(sum, All_slips))
>>> print(summed_list)
[10, 16, 19]
```